# Why those buttons are not centered

Tags: html, css

I have question as in title. I want those buttons to be centered.

I have tried many options with: `float`, `display`, `text-align`, `position`.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJVELZ

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
}
.animate {
  transition: all 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
}
.action-button {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #2980B9;
  text-shadow: 0px -2px #2980B9;
}
.red {
  background-color: #E74C3C;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #BD3E31;
  text-shadow: 0px -2px #BD3E31;
}
.green {
  background-color: #82BF56;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #669644;
  text-shadow: 0px -2px #669644;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: #F2CF66;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #D1B358;
  text-shadow: 0px -2px #D1B358;
}
.action-button:active {
  transform: translate(0px, 50px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 50px);
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="author" content="www.twitter.com/cheeriottis">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/core.css">
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate blue">Hello</a>
  <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate red">How</a>
  <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate green">Are</a>
  <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate yellow">You?</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdvRaj)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `a` tags in a container and then use `absolute` positioning and `left:50%`

```css
body{
  
  width:100%;
  
  
}

.center-it {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,0);
}

.animate
{
 transition: all 0.1s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
}

.action-button
{
  float:left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;

}

.blue
{
 background-color: #3498DB;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #2980B9;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #2980B9;
}

.red
{
 background-color: #E74C3C;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #BD3E31;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #BD3E31;
}

.green
{
 background-color: #82BF56;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #669644;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #669644;
}

.yellow
{
 background-color: #F2CF66;
 border-bottom: 5px solid #D1B358;
 text-shadow: 0px -2px #D1B358;
}

.action-button:active
{
 transform: translate(0px,50px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px,50px);
 border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta name="author" content="www.twitter.com/cheeriottis">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/core.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="center-it">
  <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate blue">Hello</a>
  <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate red">How</a>
  <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate green">Are</a>
  <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate yellow">You?</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One question. Why I cannot center it while using position:relative;?

Comment: Because when you use `relative`, the `center-it` doesn't know the sum of widths of the 4 links and for that reason, `transform: translate(-50%,0)` cannot determine the offset. Whereas in the case of `absolute` positioning, the width of the `center-it` is exactly equal to the sum of width of 4 links inline.

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {      
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center; /* add this */        
}    
.action-button {
  /* float:left; */ /* remove this */
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/bdMwxa)

Answer (score 2):

Your buttons are not centered because you are floating them to the left. When using `text-align` you need to apply that to the parent element and not the element you want to be centered.

As far as your Codepen is concerned remove `float: left;` from `.action-button` and move `text-align: center;` from `.action-button` to `body`.

```css
body {  
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.action-button {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNxLqm)

Although you may have done this in your actual code and not in the Codepen I would advise to add you links to a containing element, something like the pseudo markup below.

```html
<div class="nav">
    <a href=""></a>
    <a href=""></a>
    <a href=""></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> html

```
 <div class="holder">
  <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate blue">Hello</a>
  <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate red">How</a>
  <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate green">Are</a>
  <a href="#" class="action-button shadow animate yellow">You?</a>
    </div>
```

> css

```
 .holder{
      width: 100%;
      float:left;
      border:1px solid #ccc;
      text-align:center;
    }
    .holder a{
      text-align:center;
    }
```

> remove float:left from anchor tag.

```
.action-button {
  /* float: left; */ /*here remove it from this class you are using */
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```